# go to logout page after specified time - issue because of header command called with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, header, logout

I am working with api in php/ajax and i have in every page included test if a user hasnt been logged out because of inactivity after a certain time. It works but in some moments i have troubles. Here's the story:

I have one file called index.php. Index.php has a div - let's name it 'div'. It also has some buttons - let's name it "new" and "modify". When i press a button, body of file new.php and modify.php is loaded via ajax method to 'div'. So far so good. But when user becomes inactive for certain time it should logout him. And it does. But unfortunatelly - and it's clear why it is happening - logout page is not printed into index.php, but to the body of "div". It's easy to understand - pressing "new" button moves me to new.php. New.php checks if i am logged in - i am not so it redirects me to logout.page so new.php is resulting logout page and it becomes a body of my "div". Here's the question: how to redirect whole page (index.php) to logout page if i am logged out and not print it in div. 
Remember that pressing "new" button doesnt refresh index.php becuase i use ajax. It only refreshes my div. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do your redirect in `new.php`, instead make that PHP script return some particular value when the user is logged out, analyze that output in your AJAX call and do the redirect via javascript if necessary.

In other words:

- if `new.php` succeeds do what you normally do
- if `new.php` returns some "authentication failure" status, do your redirect

The best way is to encapsulate AJAX responses in a JSON object so you can have both data and response codes for easier analizing on the javascript side.

Comment: your idea is in my opinion serious security threat. that kind of verification shouldnt be done via ajax - you cant trust a user

Comment: I don't understand the security concern, the ajax response is generated by your PHP script not by the user

Comment: You want me to redirect user with javascript. because javascript is clientside language malicious user can prevent redirection.

Comment: so? redirecting isn't a security measure, it's just something to do **after** being denied access. You might just show an error message instead of redirecting, or even do nothing. The point is that the actual user verification is done by PHP

Comment: after more thinking i consider you may be right :)) but it makes my code to have a lot modifications :/ +1 for you:)

Comment: easy modifications is needed, just load redirect code from where are you now making redirect, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

How about using javascript redirect ? You really do not need to care about "hacker" users, because they will not have any permissions without logging in, so just redirect normal users with:

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.location="/logout.php";</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - change "3000" to any number of miliseconds (e.g. if it's 15 minutes, set it to "900000")

```
<script>

(function(){
  setTimeout( function(){
      window.location = "www.yourawesomesite.com/logout";
    }
  ,3000)
})();

</script>
```